# Unblocking websites using /etc/hosts

Tags: osx, browser, hosts

I cannot unblock certain websites that were previously blocked from /etc/hosts.

Here is what the file looks like:

```
0.0.0.0 facebook.com
:: facebook.com
0.0.0.0 youtube.com
:: youtube.com
```

When I remove the youtube entries, I can visit youtube. However, when I remove the facebook entries, facebook is still blocked.

I am on Mac OSx Sierra and have ran `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` and `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper;sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` in attempt to flush the DNS cache to no avail.